# Introduction to windows azure,simple app worked locally but not in the staging envirnonment

Tags: .net, azure, azure-worker-roles

I am following the first hands on lab
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WAZPlatformTrainingCourse_IntroToWindowsAzureLabVS2010

After doing all step by step, it worked locally, but after I deployed to staging environment, its not working.
It shows me the classic generic error.

http://65a48b0a1c1f4813aa82aeb31a400638.cloudapp.net/

I dont even know what to check, I am very newbie to azure development!!!

Well, suddenly the local environment is not working, and the problem is in this line in global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((configName, configSetter) =>
            {
                configSetter(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName));
            });

        }
```

**External component has thrown an exception.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
Source Error:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the files from Step 3 in the lab, be sure that you check the config file

ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg

They should have something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="GuestBook" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration">
  <Role name="GuestBook_WebRole">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=levalenciaguestbook;AccountKey=wVRP+PuQx6X1uJoFu+teVlkVbS36gI7eT7yLxvrsKiyXPcCramC1VVt2NaULoPyKBi8V0iswM5lzwzampn6qwQ==" />
      <Setting name="DataConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=levalenciaguestbook;AccountKey=wVRP+PuQx6X1uJoFu+teVlkVbS36gI7eT7yLxvrsKiyXPcCramC1VVt2NaULoPyKBi8V0iswM5lzwzampn6qwQ==" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
  <Role name="GuestBook_WorkerRole">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;AccountKey=wVRP+PuQx6X1uJoFu+xpn6qwQ==" />
      <Setting name="DataConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;AccountKey=wVRP+x+x==" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Comment: at least it works locally now, I need to check if it will work on the cloud